# Работа с несколькими таблицами с помощью JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте, у меня есть БД mysql и в ней несколько таблиц. Я хочу в Java с помощью JDBC вывести одну таблицу, но т.к. в БД в таблице есть внешние ключи, появились трудности. Я пытался сделать путём сравнение внешнего ключа в основной таблице с id второстепенной таблицы и тем самым выводить название, а не цифру (ключ), но как я понял, нельзя одновременно работать с несколькими таблицам. Как мне поступить? [[image: Код подключения]] Ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAhFu.jpg)

Comment: как насчет использования  конструкции [join](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))?

Comment: Это можно решить с помощью `JOIN` в MySql. Пытались уже?

Comment: Мне реально страшно за будущее этой страны...

Comment: Хватит меня бить, мне нужно это сдать и забыть. А про Join я что-то совсем забыл, щас буду гуглить и вспоминать, спасибо) @Barmaley

Comment: @BornToNight сдашь и забудешь, потом лет через 10 из-за тебя накроектся очередной спутник :(

Comment: @Barmaley Слишком оптимистично как-то. Это хорошо будет, если я буду хотяб часть спутников программировать.